# Building Boost Python with mingw on Windows7 64bit

Tags: c++, python, boost, windows-7, boost-python

I've been trying to build boost python for about two days now and am incredibly frustrated. When I build the library, it tells me that it was built successfully.
When I try to run anything using the library i get errors such as;

undefined reference to *imp*__ZN5boost6python6detail11init_moduleEPKcPFvvE

In function ZNK5boost6python9type_info4nameEv:
undefined reference to *imp*__ZN5boost6python6detail12gcc_demangleEPKc

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening, but I'd appreciate any ideas

BTW, I'm using boost1.49.0 with python 3.0 and the other libraries seem to have been built fine. I've already used the serialization library and it works.

Let me know if you need any more info.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you build Python yourself, or are you using the binaries distributed from python.org? Also, the [Boost.Python docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/news.html) imply that Python 3.x support is not in official releases yet, only in trunk, so that would definitely be an issue...

Comment: What does your bjam/b2 build command look like? What does bjam --debug-configuration say?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I got it figured out. The problems were python 3 and boost wasn't properly linking the static libraries. I switched to python2.7 and defined BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB before loading any headers. Everything works fine now.
Thanks for the help.